# How do we define discriminant over a commutative ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, definition

Let $f$ be a nonconstant polynomial over a field $F$.

Since there **exists** a splitting field of $f$ over $F$, $f$ can be decomposed as $f=c\prod_{i=1}^n (X-\alpha_i)$

Hence, it is possible to define $D_f=c^{2n-2} \prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n} (\alpha_i-\alpha_j)^2$ and call it the **discriminant of $D_f$**.

However, I saw in wikipedia that discriminant of a **monic** polynomial over a **commutative ring** is important in algebraic geometry, but how do I define the discriminant in this case?

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $f\in R[X]$ be nonconstant monic polynomial.

Then, does there always exist a ring extension $R\leq S$ such that $f$ splits over $S$?

Comment: If $R$ is a domain then there is no problem, because by [Gauss's lemma](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/oldwebpages/Math581Fall2012/Gauss.pdf) you can simply look for a factorisation over an appropriate extension $E$ of the field of fractions $F$ of $R$, giving a factorisation over the integral closure of $R$ in $E$. I don't know if something can be done over a more general ring, though.

Comment: Actually, [Wikipedia itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Discriminant_of_a_polynomial_over_a_commutative_ring) explains that one can extend the *resultant* definition of the discriminant to commutative rings and gives an example of why this is relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach using the fact that the discriminant is a symmetric polynomials in the roots.

First, consider the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[T_1, \ldots, T_n]$, and look at the "universal" monic polynomial $P(X) = \prod_{i=1}^n (X-T_i) \in R[X]$.  Its discriminant is $D=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(T_i-T_j)^2$.  This is a symmetric polynomial in the $T_i$, so it is a polynomial in the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) $\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n$.  To be clear: the ring homomorphism
$$ \mathbb{Z}[S_1, \ldots, S_n] \to \mathbb{Z}[T_1, \ldots, T_n]$$
taking each variable $S_i$ to the elementary symmetric polynomial $\sigma_i$ is injective, and its image is the set of symmetric polynomials in the variables $T_i$.  Therefore the polynomial $D$ above has a unique preimage, which we call $\Delta = \Delta(S_1, \ldots, S_n)$.

Again, just to be clear: to get the discriminant of $P$, we simply evaluate $\Delta$ at $(\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n)$.  In short, $D = \Delta(\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n)$.  Now, the thing to notice is that
$$P(X) = X^n + \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i \sigma_i X^{n-i},$$
so the discriminant of $P$ is $\Delta$ evaluated in the *coefficients of $P$* (up to a sign).

Now, we simply carry this idea over to an arbitrary commutative ring $R'$.  If $Q = X^n + \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i a_i X^{n-1}\in R'[X]$ is any monic polynomial, simply define its discriminant to be $\Delta(a_1, \ldots, a_n).$

If $Q$ splits over (an extension of) $R'$, then this definition is equivalent to the one given by the formula in your post.

As for the question whether there is always an extension of $R'$ such that a given monic polynomial $P$ splits, I suppose you can do as with fields, that is, take $S=R'[X]/(P)$.  This should contain a copy of $R'$ (because $P$ is monic), and if you repeat this process often enough, you should get an extension of $R'$ in which $P$ splits.

Comment: Nice. You may wish to be a bit more careful when applying $\Delta$ (which you defined as a polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}[S_1,\dotsc,S_n]$) to a polynomial in $R'[X]$. The quickest way to get away with it is probably to consider its image under the extension to $\Bbb{Z}[S_1,\dotsc,S_n]$ of the map $\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z} \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} R' = R'$, $a \mapsto a \otimes 1_{R'}$.

Comment: @A.P. Thanks! What I meant is exactly that.  In fact, whenever you have a ring homomorphism $R\to S$ and elements $s_1, \ldots, s_n$ of $S$, you can deduce an evaluation morphism $R[X_1, \ldots, X_n]\to S: P\mapsto P(s_1, \ldots, s_n)$.  This is the evaluation of $\Delta$ that I meant, using the natural morphism $\mathbb{Z}\to R'$ that you described.